# Trying to kick off a scheduled Jenkins job from another job

Tags: jenkins, triggers, cron, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a declarative pipeline to kick off an existing job on a schedule (with different parameters) and therefore have something similar to :-

```
pipeline any
triggers {
    cron('H 6 8 * *')
}
stages {
    stage('Remove old AMIs from account 1') {
        steps {
            script {
                b = build(job: 'another job',
                parameters: [string(name: 'ACCOUNT', value: 'account1')
// some other parameters
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Remove old AMIs from account 2')
    // ... removed for brevity
}
```

However this has the effect of running the initial job once when you kick it off, and then once again at the scheduled time (once a month on the 8th).

What I'd like to do is to schedule the target job ('another job') to run at a specific time, not the initial job above.

I've tried various combinations, and scanned search results + the docs, but I can't find anything for this particular case. I'm guessing I need something like `triggers` at the same level as `job` / `parameters` within the b = build?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve what you want using the [Parameterized Scheduler Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/).
The plugin supports setting parameters in the build schedule, thus allowing you to schedule your parameterized build to run with different configurations at different times according to the parameters.

For example consider the following pipeline:

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any
   parameters {
      string(name: 'OPTION', defaultValue: 'manual')
   }
   triggers {
       parameterizedCron('''
            0 8 * * * %OPTION=autoMorning
            0 20 * * * %PLANET=autoEvening
   ''')

   stages {
      stage('Remove old AMIs from account 1') {
         when {
            environment name: 'OPTION', value: 'manual'
         }
         steps {
            build(job: 'JobA', parameters: ...)
         }
      }
      stage('Remove old AMIs from account 1') {
         when {
            environment name: 'OPTION', value: 'autoMorning'
         }
         steps {
            build(job: 'JobB', parameters: ...)
         }
      }
      stage('Remove old AMIs from account 1') {
         when {
            environment name: 'OPTION', value: 'autoEvening'
         }
         steps {
            build(job: 'JobB', parameters: ...)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this pipeline -> when you run it manually **JobA will be executed**, every day a 8AM **JobB will be executed** and very day a 8PM **JobC will be executed**.
So each job can have its own schedule regardless of the execution type.

In your case it can be something like:

```groovy
pipeline{
   agent any
   triggers {
       // Set a customized schedule for the 'another job'
       parameterizedCron('0 8 * * * %OPTION=another')
   }
   stages {
       stage('Remove old AMIs from account 1') {
           when {
               environment name: 'OPTION', value: 'another'
           }
           steps {
               script {
                   b = build(job: 'another job',
                   parameters: [string(name: 'ACCOUNT', value: 'account1') // some other parameters
               }
           }
       }
       stage('Remove old AMIs from account 2')
       // ... removed for brevity
    }
}
```

So you have a custom schedule for you job which is not affected from manual executions.